# function with upper bounded generic argument

Tags: java, generics

Are the following two functions equivalent or is there any difference?

```
public static void foo(List<? extends Animal> animals)

public static <T extends Animal> void foo(List<T> animals)
```

Comment: very different... why do you think they are equivalent? List<? extends Animal> is not the same as List<Animal> - assuming Dog and Cat both extends Animal, a List<Dog> is not the same as a List<Animal> - second one can contain a Cat, but first one cannot

Comment: Could you explain please? Aren't both just meaning that the argument 'animals' can only be a list of Animal objcts or a list of objects of any child class of Animal?

Comment: Oops.. I think I posted the wrong question. Fixed it now. Aren't these two the same now?

Comment: It might be more useful to ask whether there’s a difference between `Collection<Animal> findSimilar(List<? extends Animal> animals, Animal similarTo)` and `<T extends Animal> Collection<T> findSimilar(List<T> animals, T similarTo)`.

Comment: You can do `animals.add(animals.get(0))` in one but not the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a bit of a difference.

Let's first inspect this method:

```java
public static <T extends Animal> void foo(List<T> animals)
```

Inside it, you know about `T` so you can use it for things. For example, you can create other generic types of the same class or work with instances of `T` where you know these can be used in the `List`:

```java
public static <T extends Animal> void foo(List<T> animals){
    T animal = animals.getFirst();//we can take out some animal and know it's of type T
    animals.add(animal);//since it's of type T, we can add it again
    List<T> subList = animals.subList(start, end);//we can also create sublists and know they have exactly the same type
}
```

However, that doesn't work with the wildcard:

```java
public static void foo(List<? extends Animal> animals) {
    Animal animal = animals.getFirst();//we just know it's an animal but we don't know which one so we can't insert it again
    //animals.add(animal);//compiler error
    List<? extends Animal> subList = animals.subList(start, end);//for the compiler, this is a different ? extends Animal
}
```

However, you can call both methods from each other:

```java
//this would result in a StackOverflowError, I just added it for demonstration
public static void foo(List<? extends Animal> animals){
    bar(animals);
}

public static <T extends Animal> void bar(List<T> animals){
    foo(animals);
}
```

This is possible because the `?` needs to be some `T`.